# Firebase - Making a homefeed of posts of people you follow (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, social-networking

whats the most scalable solution to this?

```
- posts
    - userID
    - userID
          - randomID
          - randomID
- followers
    - personB userid
          - personA userid
- following 
    - personA userid
          - personB userid
```

I have a Database structure like this. so if person A starts following person B he will be put under person B´s ID under "followers". At the same time person B will be put under persons A´s id under "following".

If a person makes a post on the App, it will be posted under "posts" and has a child with the userID of the person who posted (and under there, childs with random ids of different posts they have).

I have tried

```
let queryRef = self.ref.child("posts/\(userID)")

 queryRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    // new post from a friend 

})`
```

I'd have to use this method for every single person the user follows though which would be really slow if there is alot of people who has posted stuff!

Do you guys have any smart scalable solutions to this problem?

Comment: See firefeed.io for an example of a twitter-like app built on the Firebase Realtime Database. While the example is quite old, the data structure is still equally applicable today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really not scalable. Ideally, you'd want to fan out the data. For example, you'd create additional node, let's call it `feed`. Every time the current logged user follows another user you'd add that users' posts ids (if any) to the feed of the current user like this:

```
-feed 
   -userID
      -postID
```

Now, in the example you gave above when Person B follows Person A, if Person A has existing posts, get the `id` of those posts and store them in the `feed` under `person B id` with the `timestamp` of the post (if you have any and you want to sort out the posts on the feed):

```
let followRef = Database.database().reference().child("followers")
guard currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

followRef.child(currentUserUid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let followersArraySnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    followersArraySnapshot.forEach({ (child) in

        // child.key is the userUid of each user they follow (depends on your model)
        let refFeed = Database.database().reference().child("feed")
        refFeed.child(child.key).child("get the post ID").setValue(["timestamp" : timestamp])
     })
})
```

Then in your `FeedViewController` or wherever you need to show the feed really, you'd have to observe the feed for the current logged user (which should return the `id` of each post), then observe each post with that `id`, cache/store them in an `array` and then display them to the user.

This whole thing should look something like this:

```
var posts = [Post]() // post array (based on your post model)

func observeFeedPosts(withUserId id: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> Void) {
let feedRef = Database.database().reference().child("feed")
let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

feedRef.child(id).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    let postId = snapshot.key
     self.postRef.child(postId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {

        // snapshot.value should return your post, just transform it based on your own model 
        let post = Post.transformDataToImagePost(dictionary: dictionary, key: snapshot.key)
        self.posts.append(post)

      }
   })
}
```

That way you don't need to store the `userID` under `posts`, but the `id` of the post itself. At some point, you'd want to observe all the posts the current logged user made, so I suggest to fan out the data in a similar way - create `myPosts` node (or call it whatever you want) and store the information like so:

```
 -myPosts
     -userId
        -postId:true
```

Then all you have to do is observe this `myPosts` node, get the `postId` for the current logged user and observe the `posts` node to get the actual post value. That's it. It flattens the data. This would be my recommendation.

Comment: Wow thanks alot dude! What a great answer and interesting concept..havent even thought about doing it this way.. Just have one question, how do i obtain the ("get the post ID")? Like how do i go into the posts node and and check which posts the user has? Whats the best way of obtaining all the postIDs of the user the person is following?

Comment: Also, lets say Person B (that Person A is following) posts a new post, how will Person A get this postID in his feed in the database?

Comment: First, your post model needs to have a `id`, the `id` is usually the `snapshot.key` returned from the database, when you observe a post in the posts node. You'd have to create it, once the user taps on send. Like so, `let newPostId = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId().key`
 `let newPostReference = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(newPostId)` and that's how you'd get your post id.As for the latter, I've literally answered this is the answer above. Please, read it again. If you find the answer useful, please accept it to close the question.

Comment: Adding every post's id look like an expensive operation if there are large volume of posts by someone. If someone even has like 200 posts , 200 hits will be sent to firebase (I am not sure, I guess this is how firebase works, and calculates your bill, the number of read and writes). And everytime I post something I will need to send it to everyone's feed who follows me? Will it better to use firebase cloud functions for these stuff?